# auto decltype in virtual private method inside template class with non-virtual interface

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto, decltype

This is a question that I have mostly out of curiosity.

I have implemented a template class with a non-virtual interface. I have a class that has a public non-virtual method, which then calls a private virtual method. The following is a simplification of my code.

```
template< class T >
class MyClass {

public:

    SomeOtherClass
    some_function(
            const T & in )
    {
        return this->some_function_impl( in );
    }

protected:

    virtual SomeOtherClass
    some_function_impl(
            const T & in ) = 0;

};

class MyClassDeriv : public MyClass< int > {

private:

    SomeOtherClass
    some_function_impl(
            const int & in )
    {
         // do stuff.

         return SomeOtherClass( in );
    }

};
```

I was wondering if I can replace the non-virtual MyClass::some_function method by the following:

```
auto
some_function(
        const T & in ) -> decltype( this->some_function_impl( in ) )
{
    return this->some_function_impl( in );
}
```

I tried doing it with C++11, g++ 4.8.2, but the compiler just said that MyClass has no member called some_function_impl. What's the reason this occurs?

P.S. I simplified my code to the minimum for this question. I apologize for any typos in it.

Comment: `some_function_impl` has to at least be declared above `some_function` in order for it to be used in a trailing return type.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's an answer.